# Using $rootScope during protractor testing

Tags: node.js, angularjs, protractor, end-to-end, rootscope

I am trying to do an End2End test and I need to manipulate data from the Server (mocking it)...Is there a way to access $rootScope in Protractor so that I can tell the server (Node) what data I am looking for to complete a test? I would inject rootScope in a protractor as a "Before" and then when i need to manipulate the data, I can.

Please advise how to do this or if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
angular.element(document).scope();
```